# Proof of countable subadditivity of outer measure

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

I've come across the proof that starts out with: [Proof of subadditivity of the Lebesgue measure](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/71605/proof-of-subadditivity-of-the-lebesgue-measure).

So the final line of the proof is

$$m(\cup E_n) \leq \sum m(E_n) + \epsilon $$

"But $\epsilon > 0$ being arbitrary, the result follows."

I don't understand how we can conclude the proof? 
They have seem to take $\epsilon = 0$

However $\epsilon$ can't be zero because that would go against the fact that "there exits a countable collection $[I_{n,i}]$ of open intervals such that $E_n \subset \cup I_{n,i} $ satisfying $\sum l(I_{n,i}) < m(E_n) + 2^{-n}\epsilon$"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a fact about real numbers: if $a,b\in\mathbb R$ with $a<b+\varepsilon$ for all $\varepsilon>0$, then $a\leq b$; if not, then $a>b$, and we get a contradiction by choosing $\varepsilon=\frac{a-b}{2}$.

Comment: but in my case, $a$ is dependent on $\epsilon$ because I've chosen such an $a$ such that it satisfies that condition for a given $\epsilon$. How do I know that the same $a$ will work for smaller values of $\epsilon$

Comment: @numberphile No, as $a$ is the measure of the union, and $b$ the sum of the measures. Both are fixed.

Comment: Yeah, sorry for the dumb question. I got confused along the way between what varies with $\epsilon$ and what doesn't. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Two facts:

- Here $\epsilon $ is not taken $0$.
- If you ever want to show that $x\leq y$ it is easy to do this by giving yourself an $\epsilon$ room  because if you show that $x<y+r$ for every $r>0$ then ultimately you can make $r$ as small as  you like but then also you have  $x<y+r$ which implies $x\leq y$.